# What does @ ".intvec" mean in the declaration/initialization of int const __vector_table[] @ ".intvec" = { }

Tags: c, embedded

This line of C code came from  declaration/initialization  of a vector table for a microcontroller.  There must be special meaning to @ ".intvec".  What is the meaning behind this?

Just a note: This process takes place before the execution of main() function.

The toolchain is IAR, and `.intvec` is located at 0x00000000.

Comment: This would be a language extension provided by the tool chain you're using for the microcontroller you are building for.  The documentation for that toolchain should have the information.  If you want an answer here, you're more likely to get it if you at least provide information on the the toolchain you're using and the microcontroller.

Comment: As an example, the IAR toolchain for ARM uses this syntax (or something very similar) to indicate that the `__vector_table[]` array should be placed in the section named `.intvec` defined in the linker configuration file. I wouldn't be surprised if other toolchains do the same.

Comment: @MichaelBurr - I am using IAR for ARM and  .intvec refers to memory address of 0x00000000.  Thanks.

Comment: It would have been useful to include the code toy are _describing_ for context.  The information about the toolchain and address should be in the question not added as a comment; answers need to address the question, not the comments, so useful contextual information should be added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is non-standard C code. `@` is often used as a non-standard extension when you wish to declare a variable at a specific memory location. In this case it points at a segment `.intvec` which will be reserved in your linker file, which is also written in some custom, tool-dependent way.

In this specific case, they want to ensure that the interrupt vector table is allocated at the designated address for it. Most likely the MCU will expect it to be placed at a certain address, commonly at the very beginning or at the very end of the memory map.

Answer (score 1):

In IAR `@` is a linker directive extension to locate an object either at an absolute address, within a specific linker section or in a specific register.  On your target, no doubt the interrupt vector table is at 0x00000000.

See the section *Controlling data and function placement in memory* the [toolchain documentation](http://netstorage.iar.com/SuppDB/Public/UPDINFO/006738/arm/doc/EWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf).

[image]